# Check requests to server from the application written in Flash

Tags: flash, http, websocket, communication, wireshark

Is there a way to find what sort of requests does a Flash application send to a server?

I was trying to see what information a client sends to the server using Chrome "inspect element", but it shows me that nothing is going on.

But for sure the communication is going on. The website I am interesting in is http://www.chesscube.com/ and every time you make a move it somehow sends it to a server or may be just to another opponent. In the end of the game - it sends the game to the server for sure. But up till now, all I can see is just few images, being uploaded during the game.

Thanks for help.

P.S. I was trying to use wireshark to capture packets and in such a way to see the communication. Here what I was doing:

Pinging chesscube.com to realize its ip-address: 78.47.2.115
than I am listening only for a packages from that ip address ip.addr == 78.47.2.115
but the only thing I can see is a lot of TCP and some HTTP packages. All http packages are sending just png images of the avatars of the users. There is a chat there, and people are constantly speaking but I can no see that. I understand that it is going from another IP address, but I have no idea how I can found out it. The problem is that I can not watch for all traffic between the net and my computer, because there is so much of it, and I do not know how limit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally was able to nailed it down. May be it will be interesting to someone or if at any point of time someone will be puzzled how exactly Flash is communicating with the server - you know where to find.

So everything is going through TCP as a transport layer and RTMP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol which is actually is used for streaming video. There they are using it to stream a game.

If anyone is interested how the packet looks like - here is a the body of RTMP:

```
\00
bt5tsmdn9z\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00:\00
onMoveMade\00   Schockrae\00$com.playlogix.red5.gameserver.R5Move\00
lagPenalty\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00moveLag\00@\93\D0\00\00\00\00\00\00
cheatTypes
\00\00\00\00\00drawIfTimeElapsed\00\00time\00@\E8\CA\C0\00\00\00\00\00pingLag\00@b\E0\00\00\00\00\00\00san\00c5\00  cheatData\00fen\00?r2qkb1r/pp1npppp/2p2n2/3p4/3P1Pb1/2PBPN2/PP4PP/RNBQK2R b KQkq -\00ply\00@(\00\00\00\00\00\00\00toCoord\0034\00   fromCoord\0042\00\00
```

Here the most interesting part is:

```
cheatData\00fen\00?r2qkb1r/pp1npppp/2p2n2/3p4/3P1Pb1/2PBPN2/PP4PP/RNBQK2R
```

which is basically the PNG board representation of a chess position

More about it one can read here.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth-Edwards_Notation

It was really interesting for me to investigate it. So if anyone has anything interesting like this - feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  These applications let you inspect traffic.  You should be able to run it and filter out the communications being issued by your Flash application.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Charles web proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). Not only does it show you the traffic, it allows you to record it and view it in different ways.

Comment: It shows requests between the client and server when I use it. Maybe they're using HTTOS. I didn't originally notice you were trying to hack/cheat on a game.